# How to feature detect if iframe accepts created blob urls as src of iframe

Tags: javascript, browser-feature-detection

When it comes to support a relatively wider range of web browsers we sometimes need some kind of defensive coding where we check if some feature is supported in a specific browser/version (e.g. IE11).

It is recommended that instead of browser sniffing it is better to employ feature detection. For example  you want to use a newer web api like Shape Detection API. First you check if the API is implemented in the browser, rather than checking which browser you are runnig your app since the browsers can add/drop support in the future for a specific API, feature.

```
if ('BarcodeDetector' in window) {
   // do related stuff here
}
```

But how to detect more than the constructors or attributes etc. My specific case requires that as follows:

I need to check if my iframe accepts *created Blob urls as `src` attribute value in iframes*.
According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=blob), IE does not do that.

How can I detect that feature?

Note: As a fallback solution I think being able to throw an error on that case is also acceptable. Maybe this case described can be considered as an example of a class of browser feature detection cases and the solution in the answer can be applied to other cases of that class.

Comment: That's a quite special case actually, and there is no easy universal way to do it... By chance are you in a situation where you are sure to be in a non-sandboxes secure context?

Comment: I do not know how this case you mentioned applies or looks like.
Still this case is not specific to iframe src or object data attributes. There are a number fo cases. Yet it is special you are right. When there is no constructor or method or attribute for the fature you can easily check for those, but still there are cases how some of them behaves.

Comment: No here it's really special because there is no event fired in case of failure to load the resource. This is one of the only cases I know of where this happens. for <object> for instance it could be easily detected by listening for its`onerror` event. But `<iframe>` don't have such an event, so you can't know if it failed to load.